# What kind of change would be needed for Cow::clone to return shallow copies?

Tags: rust

I have a question related to [Rust issue #34284](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/34284). I understand why it is not possible in current Rust, but I am curious what kind of (breaking) change would be needed to avoid allocations in `Cow::clone`.

I suspect it would need some sort of lifetime specialization. Something like (pseudo-Rust):

```
impl<'a, B: ?Sized> Clone for Cow<'a, B> where B: ToOwned {
    fn clone(&'b self) -> Cow<'a, B> {
        if /*lifetimes 'a and 'b allow for optimization*/ {
            return /*shallow copy*/
        } else {
            return /*as it is today*/
        }
    }
}
```

[RFC 1210](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1210-impl-specialization.md) states that specialization based on lifetimes is not possible:

> We can't, because when the compiler goes to actually generate code
>   ("trans"), lifetime information has been erased

but later it says that

> Unfortunately, we cannot easily rule out the undesirable
>   lifetime-dependent specializations, because they can be "hidden"
>   behind innocent-looking trait bounds

Does it mean that:

- optimizing `Cow::clone` is not possible without changing the compiler so that is retains lifetime information longer?
- it would be possible to optimize only for language-defined lifetimes (`'static`), if RFC 1210 allowed it?